# How to remove word in an array at MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, string, mongodb

I need to remove a specific word from a string arrays at MongoDB, for example the word python.

```
"languages" : [ 
        "python is needed", 
        "html5 might be needed", 
        "C# barely needed"
    ]
```

I tried this but it's not working. How could i do it?

```
db.offers.update(
                      {},
                      { $pull: 
                             { languages:"python" }
                      }, 
                      { 
                          multi : true 
                      }
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) for checking if a field contains a string. So you can write a regex like below to remove all string that contains the word 'python' from an array in all the documents

```js
db.offers.update({}, {$pull: {languages: {$regex: ".*python.*"}}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working properly because it deletes the whole string. I need to remove just the word python, not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2 you can use the pipeline form of update to:

- $map over each string element in the languages array
- $split each string on the spaces
- $filter with $not and either $regexMatch or $eq to eliminate all instances of the desired word
- $reduce with $concat to reassemble them into a sting

```
db.offers.update(
        {},
        [{$set:{
              languages:{ 
                  $map: {
                    input: "$languages",
                    as: "str",
                    in: {$reduce: {
                            input: { 
                                $filter:{
                                     input:{$split: ["$$str", " "]},
                                     as: "word",
                                     cond: {$not: {
                                           $regexMatch: { 
                                               input:"$$word",
                                               regex: "python", 
                                               options: "i"
                                           }
                                     }}
                                }
                             },
                             initialValue:"",
                             in: {$concat:[
                                    "$$value",
                                    {$cond:[{$eq:["$$value",""]},""," "]},
                                    "$$this"
                             ]}
                    }}
                  }
              }
        }}],
        {multi:true}
)
```